# How to force the fan to always spin?

Tags: temperature, fan, gpu

I am using ArchLinux on an HP Pavilion dv9000t which has overheating problems. I did all what I can do to get a better air flow in the laptop and put a better thermal paste but there is still a problem:

the fan stops spinning when the CPU temperature is low (even if the GPU temperature is high, which is problematic).

I found out I can get the fan running by launching some heavy processing commands (like the `yes` command). However, it is not a solution because I need to stop this command when the CPU gets too hot and launch it again when the fan stops (so that the GPU does not get hot).

I tried to control the fan using [this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_control), but when I run `pwmconfig`, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

Do you know what can I do to get the fan always spinning?

**Edit:**

The `sensors-dectect` output is the following:

```
~/ sudo sensors-detect 
# sensors-detect revision 6170 (2013-05-20 21:25:22 +0200)
# System: Hewlett-Packard HP Pavilion dv9700 Notebook PC [Rev 1] (laptop)
# Board: Quanta 30CB

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): 
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): 
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): 
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): 
Using driver `i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.3: Intel 82801H ICH8
Module i2c-dev loaded successfully.

Next adapter: nouveau-0000:01:00.0-0 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: nouveau-0000:01:00.0-1 (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: nouveau-0000:01:00.0-2 (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

Do you want to overwrite /etc/conf.d/lm_sensors? (YES/no): 
Unloading i2c-dev... OK
Unloading cpuid... OK
```

The file `/etc/conf.d/lm_sensors` contains:

```
HWMON_MODULES="coretemp"
```

And the file `/etc/modules-load.d/lm_sensors.conf` contains:

```
coretemp
acpi-cpufreq
```

The command `sensors` outputs this:

```
~/ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +46.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 1:       +47.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +49.0°C  

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +60.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +115.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +115.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
```

Comment: I don't think the `yes` command is heavy CPU-wise. Other than that, good question :)

Comment: Have done your configuration correctly? Hve you run `sensors-detect` yet?

Comment: I already ran `sensors-detect` and I added its output to the post. For the `yes` command, I took me some time to find out it is better to increase the CPU temperature than four simultaneous `grep` on the entire hard drive (I don't know why it is CPU intensive, though).

Comment: I had the same laptop and I didn't know about this issue and one day graphic card got black out. I do see a propose solution here that may help: http://superuser.com/questions/295513/how-can-i-set-the-fan-speed-to-100-on-a-laptop

Comment: Might have some additional things to try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63588/how-do-i-get-fan-control-working

Comment: Have you seen this site: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_Speed_Control

Comment: First things first. How long has it been since you've disassembled the laptop and cleaned it as thoroughly as possible? I cleaned one yest for a friend. The airways are very small and collect lots of dust, pet hair, etc. 
Having the fan always on may not be the best solution.

Comment: @Mark Cohen: Yes, the link is in the question.

Comment: @bdowning: I did the cleaning just before I asked this question. Moreover, I found this tutorial (http://www.gabsoftware.com/tips/tutorial-how-i-forced-my-laptop-fan-to-spin-under-linux-fujitsu-amilo-xi-1554-1526-1546/) that should help me, but I didn't tried it yet.

Comment: If you have an overheating problem, and you are not overclocking then you should perform root cause analysis and repair the problem. Configuring the fan to run all the time might let the box live a little while longer but eventually it will fail. A through cleaning and potentially reapplying thermal compound seems like a more appropriate fix to me. Laptops are built tight with very little room for airflow.

Comment: @bdowning: I already did the cleaning (there were a lot of dust between the fan and the heatsink) and I changed the thermal paste. I also changed the thermal pad for a cooper shim. I don't know want I can do more than that. Moreover, I am not the only one that has this problem on this particular laptop. Look at this blog post (http://icodehead.blogspot.ca/2010/07/how-i-fixed-my-overheating-hp-dv9000.html). It explains a lot of problems and fixes for the overheating problem of this laptop. It seems to have a design flaw. It is why I need the fan to always run.

Comment: if that is truly the case then I would look to supply power by internally connecting the fan to the power supply and leave all of the bios, os, etc. out of the loop. It will make life simpler and you'll always be certain the fan is running.

Comment: The discussion at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1877114 suggests loading the it87 kernel module as well as using the acpi_enforce_resources=lax option to the kernel. Does it work for you?

Comment: @hanxue: This gives me `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'it87': No such device`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally decided to choose a hardware solution.

I cut two wires from the fan and now the fan always spin (at the max level though).

I found this solution in [this blog post](http://icodehead.blogspot.ca/2010/07/how-i-fixed-my-overheating-hp-dv9000.html).

Comment: Here an how to with a `software` solution: http://www.gabsoftware.com/tips/tutorial-how-i-forced-my-laptop-fan-to-spin-under-linux-fujitsu-amilo-xi-1554-1526-1546/

Answer (score 6):

I did a bit of excavation and found that your laptop has a flaw from the manufacturer (the NVIDIA chip, specifically) and the *only solution* is to do a "reflow" as explained [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-e-g-Windows-8/hp-pavilion-dv9000-class-action-lawsuit-motherboard-issues/td-p/1098327).

You can buy a cooling pad for the time being to make the laptop life span longer, but won't solve the temperature problem.

About not being able to run pwmconfig, the BIOS don't include (from the HP documentation) any method to manually modify the fan speed, hence pwmconfig fails as there isn't any module that allows control over this values.

For other laptops, I recommend to **check your manual/specifications** and see if they include support for this modules. Running sensors-detect isn't going to hurt if you aren't sure or your documentation don't include the information. Also remember that sometimes Linux don't include the modules even if your machine includes support, so you have to keep yourself updated with the latest kernels releases and pray.

Comment: The GPU broke this morning so I had to do a reflow. However, the problem is still present. I reflowed it at 160°C. Is it the good temperature? It already has a cooling pad but it does not seem to help in any way.

Comment: @antoyo not gonna lie to you, I'm not a expert in hardware of laptop (although I can disassemble/ensemble one), maybe asking is some specialized forum will shred some lights. _I did a small search myself about 'what's reflow', etc. but they didn't mention anything about temperature._ BTW, if my answer did help you please accept it, it kinda bogus me that I still see it in /unanswered questions ;)